# Flexdashboard on shinyapp.io with embedded images [R]

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard, reactable

I have an R flexdashboard that runs with shiny and although I have managed to host it on shinyapp.io, I cannot get images to render. I understand that normally, with a Shiny app, I would need to place the images in a 'www' folder. But with a flexdashboard there is no associated folder like that. How would I go about getting the images to load on shinyapp.io? Images show up completely fine when I run the flexdashboard locally.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok to put your images in a www folder. Make sure to reference the path. Example markdown text:

```
Built with ![](www/shiny_50.png).
```

I was having problems rendering that image until I discovered that its original resolution was too large to fit in the chart window. I used the Magick package to resize.